# Decoding base64 string?

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

I can't seem to decode this base64 string which is in the footer of a wordpress theme.  I want to be able to add more to the footer.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("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")))); ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a license violation: freethemelayouts.com created this template, and you want to delete copyright. Right?

Comment: i believe it's general thumb rule to not use any wp theme with some mysterious decoded string. i forgot where i read this, But it sound right wisdom ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `eval` with `print` and see what it says.

The full result is:

```
?>          <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->

    <!-- start Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer2">
            <div id="fl">
                <ul>

                    <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Home</a></li> 
                    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="fr">
<!-- FOOTER CREDITS LINK -->    
<big><strong>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></strong></big><br>
<small><strong><a href="http://www.freethemelayouts.com/" style="color: #656565;text-decoration: none;" title="Free WordPress Themes">WordPress Themes</a> by ImHosted <a href="http://www.imhosted.com" style="color: #656565;text-decoration: none;" title="Website Hosting">Website Hosting</a><strong></small>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end Footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?
```

Comment: @Filip I answered his question, replacing eval with print decodes the base64. Why should it be a comment? If my answer solves his problem, how does he mark a comment as the answer?